# Implementing Adaboost for multiple dimensions in Java

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, classification, adaboost

I'm working on AdaBoost implementation in Java. 
It should have work for "double" coordinates on 2D 3D or 10D.
All I found for Java is for a binary data (0,1) and not for multi-dimensional space.

I'm currently looking for a way to represent the dimensions and to initialize the classifiers for boosting.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to represent the multidimensional space in Java, and how to initialize the classifiers to begin with.

The data is something in between [-15,+15]. And the target values are 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

To use a boosted decision tree on spatial data, the typical approach is to try to find a "partition point" on some axis that minimizes the residual information in the two subtrees.  To do this, you find some value along some axis (say, the x axis) and then split the data points into two groups - one group of points whose x coordinate is below that split point, and one group of points whose x coordinate is above that split point.  That way, you convert the real-valued spatial data into 0/1 data - the 0 values are the ones below the split point, and the 1 values are the ones above the split point.  The algorithm is thus identical to AdaBoost, except that when choosing the axis to split on, you also have to consider potential splitting points.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [JBoost](http://jboost.sourceforge.net), I think it's got what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually found it and tried to play with it a little bit. It can be really useful for someone that wants to use AdaBoost. The first intention was to implement Adaboost by myself.

There are also very good tools that comes with [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) that I found that can be a great help to run and use many data mining algorithms and there also a source code available.

Comment: I don't get it, though .. you said all the things you found on worked for "binary data and not multi-dimensional space", and JBoost isn't limited to either of those, so ... I guess I'm confused as to what your question is, then?

Comment: No intentions to confuse, sorry for that.

To clarify my question:  I wanted to implement AdaBoost by myself, not just use existing version. It was part of one of my projects.

JBoost can be very useful as a reference and as a platform to run AdaBoost.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `double[]` array for each object? That is the common way of representing feature vectors in Java.

Comment: I don't think that this is the question being asked; I think the OP is curious how to use AdaBoost for real-valued data, rather than how to store everything internally.

Comment: Exactly! I'm trying to implement AdaBoost on a "real" data, represented as "double-type".